# how to discover .dlls my application is using

Tags: c++, c, dll, graphics, game-engine

i am trying my hand at using the crystal space api in my graphics applications. 
[crystal space website](http://www.crystalspace3d.org)

The applications compile fine but i am having hell with the dlls(dynamic link libraries). The compiled application crashes at run time and i suspect its because of not finding the needed dlls.

The only solution i currently have is cutting and pasting my application executable to a folder having all necessary libraries.(which is about 300mb).

Is there a way that i can find out the dlls my app needs so that i can copy them?(instead of using all dlls)

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: i am using g++ and codeblocks ide

from dr deo

Comment: what made you suspect there's a DLL problem? usually if you're missing a DLL, a clear message box is displayed with the name of the missing dll. If that doesn't happen you can almost be sure it's not a dll problem.

Comment: it displayed the messageBox about a dll missing once, but afterwards it misteriously just crashes with windows generating error reports. as if some invalid pointer is being referenced

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

`Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules.`

Comment: i tried it and it gave me this error:  
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
Whats this???

Comment: It means that one of the dlls that is required by one of the dlls required by your program is not there. That is why your program will not run. You will need to find the dll or remove that dependency somehow.

Comment: I get those same two errors from DependencyWalker on all of my applications and assemblies for GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.dll, which don't appear to _actually_ be required, because my applications still run.

Answer (score 3):

Try [***Dependency Walker***](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) By Steve Miller